# Find the missing integer in an arithmetic progression from a list in python

Tags: python

My code below return the correct missing integers for arrays of size 10, 100, 1000, 10000, and 100000, but then returns the error "Max Buffer reached: Too much information has been written to stdout. Process exited prematurely with a SIGKILL signal. "

This is preventing me from completing the Codewars exercise. Am I doing anything wrong? somehow there is a right way to complete this exercise, and I thought I had it

```
def find_missing(sequence):
    s1 = []    
    a = sequence[1] - sequence[0]
    c = sequence[0]
    s1.append(c)
    for x in range(0,len(sequence)):
        c += a
        s1.append(c)

    d = set(s1)
    e = set(sequence)
    print(d)
    print(e)
    f = [i for i in d if i not in e]

    return f[0]
```

Comment: Are you supposed to be `print()`ing the sets?

Comment: oh my gawd im so dumb. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly wouldn't `itertools.count()` with `zip()` solve this problem, e.g.:

```
import itertools as it

def find_missing(sequence):
    for x, y in zip(it.count(sequence[0], sequence[1]-sequence[0]), sequence):
        if x != y:
            return x
```

Note: Diagnostic `print()`s are probably your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says "Too much information has been written to stdout."

Remove the `print()` calls - stdout is (by default) where output from `print()` is written, so it seems the Codewars server doesn't like you printing so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could try flushing the buffer. Use a print statement like `print(a, flush=True)` and see if it works. Or just remove the print statements.